# C# Regex replace specific decimal in series

Tags: c#, regex, replace, decimal

I have a line in a file like this:

`NORMFLY 306130.10 199963.09 5000.00 300.00`

I want to use C# regex to replace the third decimal in the series with a random decimal. The value of the 3rd decimal may vary with different lines. `^NORMFLY \d+(\.\d{1,2})? \d+(\.\d{1,2})? \d+(\.\d{1,2})?` will match up to the end of the 3rd decimal, but I can't figure out how to replace the match with something different.

So for example, change:

`NORMFLY 306130.10 199963.09 **5000.00** 300.00`

to

`NORMFLY 306130.10 199963.09 **7690.56** 300.00`

Comment: Why regex? is this a homework assignment and you need regex? why not split and join?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to capture everything except the third decimal:

```
(^NORMFLY \d+(?:.\d{1,2})? \d+(?:.\d{1,2})? )\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^++++++++++++++++
captured                                     not captured
```

Then you can replace it with `"$1" + someRandomNumber`. `$1` refers to the first capturing group, which in this case is everything except the third decimal.

[Try it online.](https://regex101.com/r/Yd6q6v/1/)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Now how to add/subtract random decimal from the 'not captured' value ?

Comment: @user3602836 so instead of replacing it with a random value, you want to add a random number to it? Then you will have to write another regex that captures the third number. Now match the string against the new regex. Extract the third number, parse it, add a random number to it. Then, replace the part captured with the new group.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Regex:

```
var line = @"NORMFLY 306130.10 199963.09 5000.00 300.00";

var split = line.Split(' ').ToArray();
split[3] = 123.45m.ToString();//random goes here
var result = string.Join(" ", split);

Console.WriteLine(result);//NORMFLY 306130.10 199963.09 123.45 300.00
```

**PS**: Do not use regex when it is not needed.

Comment: I already have a solution that iterates each line of a text file & parses one line at a time using split. I wanted to see if regex could be more efficient.

Comment: No, you probably would not considerably benefit from it. For example, having text with length 'n' and number of character 'c' in regex you will make O(n*c) comparisons which actually doesn't make sense, cause you don't care about those symbols at all and those comparisons is meaningless. In my example you just performing comparison and splitting with one whitespace character.